# PHP changing value inside JS

Tags: php, jquery, html

I would like to change the text color depending of what page is clicked using PHP.

**HTML**

```
<a class="link" href="index.php?col=red">Red</a>
<a class="link" href="index.php?col=gre">Green</a>
<a class="link" href="index.php?col=yel">Yellow</a>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['col'])) {
        $color = $_GET['col'];
    }else{
        $color = "red";
    }
?>
<div class="toChange">
    Color is changing
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('.link').click(function () {

    var jcolor = <?php echo $color; ?>;

    if (jcolor == "red") {
        $(".toChange").css({
            "color": "red"
        });
    }
    if (jcolor == "gre") {
        $(".toChange").css({
            "color": "green"
        });
    }
    if (jcolor == "yel") {
        $(".toChange").css({
            "color": "yellow"
        });
    }
});
```

Why does not work?
I also tried to insert a `console.log(jcolor)` for to see if the `jcolor` takes the correct value and os ok.

Comment: Edit:  thanks for reply originally the code was with a number this i why I forget ' '. The problem now is that when you select a color the text changes colo for few millisecond then it returns black. I think is a problem of refresh or something similar. So when i click a color the text color change for a bit millisecond then the page refresh and text returns black. How can I avoid refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP(server-side) runs first when page reload after PHP javascript(client-side) code runs...

So,

**This code runs first when page loads**

```
<?php
        if (isset($_GET['col'])) {
            $color = $_GET['col'];
        }else{
            $color = "red";
        }
  ?>
```

Now, color is red

**When you click on the link**

this JS will run  first

```
<script>

    $('.link').click(function(){

        var jcolor = <?php echo $color; ?>;


        if (jcolor == "red") {
            $(".toChange").css({"color": "red"});

        }
        if (jcolor == "gre") {
            $(".toChange").css({"color": "green"});

        }
        if (jcolor == "yel") {
            $(".toChange").css({"color": "yellow"});

        }


    });

    </script>
```

it will change the color, but after that page will reload because you clicked on the link...

Now, let you clicked on Green

```
<a class="link" href="index.php?col=gre">Green</a>
```

Your new URL Will be index.php?col=gre

This code will run again

```
<?php
        if (isset($_GET['col'])) {
            $color = $_GET['col'];
        }else{
            $color = "red";
        }
  ?>
```

So, the problem is instead of `.click` event of javascript use. `(document).ready` and your problem will be solved...

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var jcolor = <?php echo $color; ?>;


            if (jcolor == "red") {
                $(".toChange").css({"color": "red"});

            }
            if (jcolor == "gre") {
                $(".toChange").css({"color": "green"});

            }
            if (jcolor == "yel") {
                $(".toChange").css({"color": "yellow"});

            }


        });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`var jcolor = <?php echo $color; ?>;`

to this:

`var jcolor = '<?php echo $color; ?>';`

**Note: this is vulnerable to XSS.** You are injecting code directly from user input and this is extremely dangerous. Sanitize this input before printing it into the page.

Comment: Thanks but almost works. Now the text changes for a bit of millisecond and then return black. Maybe there a re a loop problem or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your script by below code, No need to trigger click event on `.link` because you already clicked on link (`<a>`) and got color from URL,
Also whenever you assign values from PHP variable to JS, Put Single or Double quotes around PHP code like this `'<?php echo $color; ?>'`

```
<script>

    var jcolor = '<?php echo $color; ?>';


    if (jcolor == "red") {
        $(".toChange").css({"color": "red"});
    }

    if (jcolor == "gre") {
        $(".toChange").css({"color": "green"});
    }

    if (jcolor == "yel") {
        $(".toChange").css({"color": "yellow"});
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS expecting string value and that 
because later on you compare towards `if (jcolor == "red") {`,

so what you actually doing is assigning variable to another which is i am sure it will print you an error if you look up the console you will find `undefined` for the mentioned variable

> > so all what you need is just add the value as a string inside ""

```
var jcolor = "<?php echo $color; ?>";
```